# Pass Info from next template if I click in on item of my catalog

Tags: python, django

Im doing a web app, where I have a catalog of products, and I want when I click in one of this items the next template have info about the Item was I clicked (product name, img and news for this item)

but idk how to do without doing a template for each product in my db
I hope u can help me

ITS MY FIRST POST IN STACK-OVERFLOW, SORRY IF I MISSED AN ESSENTIAL INFO

```
My models.py 

class products_menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to= '', default="../media/digi_flex.png" )
    slug = models.SlugField()
    mfq = models.CharField(db_column='MFQ', max_length=30, choices=ENGEENER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
```

```
My views.py 

def catalog(request):
    prods = products_menu.objects.all().order_by('mfq')
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'prods':prods})
```

And part my home.html where I show my dump of items

```
home.html

        <div class="container-fluid tm-container-content tm-mt-60">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <h1 class="col-6 tm-text-primary" align="center">
                    Productos
                </h1>
            </div>

    
    <div class="row">
    {% for products_menu in prods %}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <div class="panel panel-turquoise">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">{{products_menu.name}}</h3>
                </div>
                    <a href="{% url 'fail' %}"> <img src="{{products_menu.img.url}}" width="280" height="200" ></a>
                    <span class="tm-text-gray-light" align="">Ing.{{products_menu.mfq}}</span>
            </div>            
        </div>
    {% endfor %} 
    </div>
```

I want to if I click in one product img, redirect to 'fail' template with info about the item I clicked

Comment: Why did you use `href="{% url 'fail' %}"`?

Comment: Oh yeah fail its for the context of my app (failure register in a production line) and I named this view fail, because shows the product for example (FORD-ecu Nissan-ecu) and last fails registers in DB and I need show the product name, img and engeener name in fail.html

Answer (score 0):

fail its for the context of my app (failure register in a production line) and I named this view fail, because shows the product for example (FORD-ecu Nissan-ecu) and last fails registers in DB and I need show the product name, img and engeener name in fail.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% load static %}
    {% block cta %}

    <div class="container-fluid tm-container-content tm-mt-60">
        <div class="row mb-4">
            <center>
            <h2 class="col-12 tm-text-primary">{{name}}</h2>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div class="row tm-mb-90">            
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src="{{img}}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                <h3 class="col-12 tm-text-primary">{{mfq}}</h3>
                    <div class="col-md-15">
```